# Left join when there is no primary key (glue 2 given queries to one if possible)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In game have two simple entities Player and Alliance and I need to fetch all users of same nation with alliance name ( if they are in any alliance get name, otherwise alliance name is null).

```
class Base(object):
     def __tablename__(self):
       return self.__name__.lower()

     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)

class PlayerModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'players'
    alliances_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    username = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    nation = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    score = Column(String(20), default=0)

class AllianceModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'alliances'
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    nation = Column(String(20), nullable=False)


//query

for player in session.query(PlayerModel).filter(PlayerModel.nation.like(nation)):
    alliance =session.query(AllianceModel).filter(AllianceModel.id==player.alliance_id).first()
    result.append({'username':player.username, 'alliance':alliance.name})
```

Can I connect this to only one query ? 
(I know use join when there is foreign key, but player can be out of any alliance and alliances_id can be null).

Comment: Your `AllianceModel` is missing the definition for `id`. This is just a simple one-to-many relationship, what makes you think it won't work?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It inherits from Base column id

Comment: Ah, indeed, missed that. So, that has a primary key, so normal relationships will Just Work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the `alliances_id` column as a foreign key:

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class PlayerModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'players'
    alliances_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True, ForeignKey('AllianceModel.id'))
    alliance = relationship('AllianceModel')
    username = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    nation = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    score = Column(String(20), default=0)
```

Then simply refer to `player.alliance`:

```
for player in session.query(PlayerModel).filter(PlayerModel.nation.like(nation)):
    result.append({'username':player.username, 'alliance': player.aliance.name if player.aliance is not None else ''})
```

If you are unwilling or unable to add a `ForeignKey()` constraint to `alliances_id`, you can also add that information to the `relationship()` declaration:

```
    alliances_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    alliance = relationship('AllianceModel', foreign_keys='AllianceModel.id')
```

Comment: @PaolaJ.: Hrm, I may have misunderstood the documentation there. Try just a string instead of a list.